# Box (div) is placed lower than the first?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make different boxes that are placed in the same line using CSS.

However, without any style rule (at least that I've noticed) making it do so, the second box is lower than the first. Why is that? How can I fix it?

If you have any question, feel free to ask, I'll do my best to answer.

Thank you in advance.

Code snippet below.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7Lddnho/2/)

```css
.index-links {
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  padding: 1%;
}
.index-link {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 0.5%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
.index-link > .index-link-perms::before {
  content: " | "
}
```

```html
<div class="index-links">
  <br>
  <div class="index-link" data-color="black" data-x-index="1" data-y-index="1">Link 1<span class="index-link-perms">Access: Everyone</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="index-link" data-color="pink" data-x-index="2" data-y-index="1">Link 2<span class="index-link-perms">Access: SM</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the br tag between the divs.

```
<div class="index-links">
  <br>
  <div class="index-link" data-color="black" data-x-index="1" data-y-index="1">Link 1<span class="index-link-perms">Access: Everyone</span>
  </div>
  <div class="index-link" data-color="pink" data-x-index="2" data-y-index="1">Link 2<span class="index-link-perms">Access: SM</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh.... Well that was dumb. I was using an `<ul>` before and wanted more spacing, that's why I had it there and forgot to remove it.... Sorry for wasting a bit of your time.

Answer (score 0):

change the CSS as below

```
.index-links {
  display:flex;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 5%;
  padding: 1%;
}
```